# Load an array of NSNumbers from file and making them mutable

Tags: iphone, load

One way I've considered is creating a temporary array and loading the array of `NSNumbers` into it, then alloc the mutable array, then if loaded array is not nil or empty `addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:[[temparr objectAtIndex:i] intValue]],` but it seems such a roundabout way of doing it.

This is so that I can modify the numbers and array contents in the app.

Is there a shorter, more to-the-point method of doing the same? It's quite common to load arrays/dicts from somewhere only to find their contents immutable, and I'd like to learn the most straightforward way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot put NSNumbers in a mutable array and expect to be able to change their values. See the code in the question for the workaround I used.

Answer (score 1):

You can not make `NSNumber` objects mutable, they are immutable objects by design.

If you want to make a mutable deep copy of the array, that is, a mutable copy of the array and a mutable copy of its contents (when possible; for example, in the case of `NSNumber`s you can't), you can do something like this:

```
@interface NSArray (MutableCopyDeep)
- (NSMutableArray *) mutableCopyDeep;
@end

@implementation NSArray (MutableCopyDeep)

- (NSMutableArray *) mutableCopyDeep {
    NSMutableArray *returnAry = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:[self count]];
    for (id anObject in self) {
        id aCopy = nil;
        if ([anObject respondsToSelector:@selector(mutableCopyDeep)]) {
            aCopy = [anObject mutableCopyDeep];
        } else if ([anObject respondsToSelector:@selector(mutableCopyWithZone:)]) {
            aCopy = [anObject mutableCopy];
        } else if([anObject respondsToSelector:@selector(copyWithZone:)]) {
            aCopy = [anObject copy];
        } else {
            aCopy = [anObject retain];
        }

        [returnAry addObject:aCopy]; 
        [aCopy release];
    }

    // Method name prefixed with "mutableCopy" indicates that the returned
    // object is owned by the caller as per the Memory Management Rules.
    return returnAry;
} 

@end
```

Comment: It's no problem loading to a mutable array, it's that the objects in them are immutable that makes user data 'uneditable'. Or do you mean that it goes through all objects inside and make them mutable, including NSNumber, NSString->NSMutableString etc?

Comment: @Henrik What kind of objects does the array contain? In your question, you mention `NSNumber` objects, which are immutable. You can not make them mutable.

Comment: So the only way is to recreate them, like in my example. What useful objects, glad they added them... thanks for info, will rephrase the question.

Comment: NSNumbers can't be changed: correct, but your answer didn't solve the problem, which was mainly me having the wrong expectations of the built-in objects. :)